# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Where is Mobile Test Workbench client app for iOS?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

Step 1 of the Worklight 6.0 documentation for "Installing the mobile test client on an iOS device" says to "Launch the Apple App store from your mobile device and search for Rational Test Workbench Mobile Client", but, doing so on my iPhone 5 has no results.

Where can I find this app?

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with the Apple app store submission and the client app was not accepted due to Apple restrictions. The development team is looking into alternatives. For now, testing is only available via the emulator.

Comment: Hi Barbara, I have checked the app store today and still cannot find the mobile client test app. Do you have any update on this? Thanks.

Comment: Any update on this??  It only takes a few weeks to get an app approved on the Apple store...does it really have to be approved there?  Can't we just get the code and self-sign with our certificate to use the app on our local devices?